# open bootstrap 5.2 modal on page load

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

I have been using Bootstrap with JQuery and have a code snippet which shows a Modal when a page is loaded. With v5.2 of Bootstrap, we are discouraged from using JQuery (a good thing) but the documentation is very sketchy, I'm afraid.  Basically, given a modal in HTML:

```
<div class="modal auto-modal">
```

I want to replace the JQuery line:

```
$(.auto-modal).modal('show')
```

to pure JavaScript. I have tried:

```
const elem = document.querySelector('.auto-modal')
const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(elem)
```

and `modal` is `null`. The same is true with `getInstance(elem)` or even replacing `elem` with the selector `.auto-modal`

Can anyone help me show programatically (in pure JavaScript) a modal created in HTML? In other words, not created in JavaScript with a line like:

```
const modal = new bootstrap.Modal('.auto-modal')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry, I found a typo in my code. The two lines shown do work.